# CSS collapsing space between items in two columns

Tags: html, css

I have a container in which I would like to display items as though they were in two columns.
Each item has a different height because the content in it varies.

This is currently what it looks like:
[image: first]

I would like to remove the extra space between items vertically to look closer to this:
[image: second]

so that it looks as though the items are stacking.

A link to my sample code: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/oc1XT4ia9GdIc4rzZ41Q?p=preview

Comment: It is certainly dupe. I saw exactly the same problem, don't remember where...

Comment: @nicael please point me to it if you can, I've been searching

Comment: Can't be done with just CSS; you'll need JavaScript.

Comment: @j08691 can you elaborate?

Comment: You can use two divs. Put all the left blocks in the first div and the right blocks in the second. You could use `float:left` on both divs.

Comment: ill add it as an answer in a set but [here is my version](http://plnkr.co/edit/nMwKOPDixlUu21fmuvkD?p=preview)

Comment: @AndyG I can't use a 2 div solution, these items are dynamically added

Comment: @user1066946 , not a bad solution, but this is double the processing. Also, I am looking for a solution that doesn't involve two divs as separate columns

Comment: Even though the items are added dynamically it is still possible to use two divs, but requires more work.

Comment: true, but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve double processing. I was looking for a CSS solution, not a javascript solution

Comment: @EliteOctagon I've updated the answer, you could `ng-repeat` the intermediate floating div, and listen for resize to change the column count to how you want it, the Q was on 2 columns so thats what I put as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the question is using AngularJS this answer is compatible with that.

You'll need to create a divs wrapping around the repeat, and a repeat for each column you want, and then display or hide elements in there by `ng-show="($index)%2==columnIndex"`.

Then float the two wrapping divs, and add a standard clearfix to the 1px solid black container so it wraps around the floating elements.

```js
'use strict';

var app = angular.module( 'myApp', [] );

app.controller( 'myCtrl', [ '$scope', function ( $scope ){
  
  $scope.value = 'test';
  $scope.items = [];
  var count = 10;
  
  for(var i=0; i<count; i++){
    var item = {
      height: Math.round(Math.random()*30) + 20
    };
    $scope.items.push(item);
  }

}] );
```

```css
.itemContainer {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 1px;
  display: block;
}

.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
 
.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class='itemContainer clearfix'>
      <div style="display:inline-block; float:left; width:40%;">
        <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items" style="height: {{item.height}}px" ng-show="($index)%2==1" >
          {{item}}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="display:inline-block; float:left; width:40%;">
        <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items" style="height: {{item.height}}px" ng-show="($index)%2==0" >
          {{item}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can do a repeat around the repeat wrapping `float:left` elelements, and specify how many columns you want, and if you want dynamic resizing of columns youll have to watch for resizes and change the column size with it.

To prevent the double processing issue you'd ideally use a filter, and not ng-show.

In the future hopefully we can use the [flexible boxes layout module](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) without breaking it for certain browsers.

Comment: working off of your idea, I wrote a directive which accomplishes this: http://plnkr.co/edit/UyRS0clrCwDpSrYgBsXS?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record. This is [**an HTML and CSS-only**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qp4uZ/) version of one approach to achieve this.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="LeftColumn">
    <div class="left_cell">Just</div>
    <div class="left_cell">The</div>
    <div class="left_cell"></div>
    <div class="left_cell"></div>
</div>
<div id="RightColumn">
    <div class="right_cell">For</div>
    <div class="right_cell">Record</div>
    <div class="right_cell"></div>
    <div class="right_cell"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#LeftColumn {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}

#RightColumn {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin-left:4px;
}

.left_cell {
    width:200px;
    height:30px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin-bottom:2px;
}

.right_cell {
    width:200px;
    height:42px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin-bottom:2px;
}
```

Check the [**fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qp4uZ/). As you can see, the thing is just to put the contents of each column on **separate** `div` elements, and float the two `div`s.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research, I see that it is indeed difficult to do with just CSS, so I wrote a small AngularJS directive to do some of the processing.

Demo Here: http://plnkr.co/edit/UyRS0clrCwDpSrYgBsXS?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module( 'myApp', [] );

app.controller( 'myCtrl', [ '$scope', function ( $scope ){

  $scope.value = 'test';
  $scope.items = [];
  var count = 20;

  for(var i=0; i<count; i++){
    var item = {
      height: Math.round(Math.random()*30) + 20,
      value: Math.round(Math.random()*30) + 20
    };
    $scope.items.push(item);
  }

}] );

app.directive('columns', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        itemList: '=', 
        colCount: "@"
    },
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
      //console.log(scope.itemList);
      var numCols = 3;
      var colsArr = [];
      for(var i=0; i< numCols; i++){
        colsArr.push(angular.element("<div class='column'>Col "+(i+1)+"</div>"));
         elm.append(colsArr[i]);
      }

      angular.forEach(scope.itemList, function(value, key){
        var item = angular.element("<div class='item' style='height:"+value.height+"px;'>"+value.value+"</div>");
        // find smallest column
        var smallestColumn = getSmallestColumn();
        angular.element(smallestColumn).append(item);

      });

      function getSmallestColumn(){
        var smallestHeight = colsArr[0][0].offsetHeight;
        var smallestColumn = colsArr[0][0]; 
        angular.forEach(colsArr, function(column, key){ 
          if(column[0].offsetHeight < smallestHeight){
            smallestHeight = column[0].offsetHeight;
            smallestColumn = colsArr[key]; 
          }
        }); 
        console.log(smallestColumn);
        return smallestColumn;
      }
    }
  };
});
```

with this being the html:

```
<columns item-list="items" col-count='3' class='itemContainer'></columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new flex display method to achieve this.

### HTML

```
<div >
<div style="height: 45px;"></div>
<div style="height: 31px;"></div>
<div style="height: 31px;"></div>
<div style="height: 34px;"></div>
<div style="height: 27px;"></div>
<div style="height: 23px;"></div>
<div style="height: 41px;"></div>
<div style="height: 34px;"></div>
<div style="height: 48px;"></div>
<div style="height: 47px;"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
body > div {
    height: 220px;
    padding: 1px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    border: 1px solid;
}
body > div > div {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin: 1px;
}
```